# How do I change the line color of the tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

After two training, I recorded the errors on the tensorboard.

The picture below is that.

[image]

Both lines are orange and difficult to distinguish.

The smaller of the two lines is the first experiment, the larger the error is the second experiment.

How can I set the line color differently each time I learn?

And if you look at the picture above, how do you get rid of a straight line?

Finally, if you look at the picture, there is a faint afterimage. I want to get rid of this.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write the results of each experiment to a different subdirectory, using a different writer. TensorBoard will present the logs from each subdirectory with different colors and with their names on the left.

The straight lines are for the same reason, TensorBoard thinks it's all a single experiment, so it jumps from step 60k to step 0 (because logs were written in that order).

Comment: very thanks you !!

I used this code.

->file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter ('logs', sess.graph)

According to you, can I write one more line of code like this?

->file_writer2 = tf.summary.FileWriter ('logs', sess.graph)

Comment: @ddjfjfjdjfiejdn Yes, but use different subdirectories for each one (e.g. `logs/exp1`, `logs/exp2`).